# Laravel Non-static method Mavinoo\LaravelBatch\LaravelBatch::update() should not be called statically

Tags: php, laravel

In a laravel proyect i have this error in Notification controller

The error appears when trying to open a notification, the notification is sent but the user who must view it when opening it appears the error.

> `Error: Non-static method Mavinoo\LaravelBatch\LaravelBatch::update() should not be called statically Line: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\Unifiedtransform-master\app\Http\Controllers\NotificationController.php:28`

In this code:

```
* Display a listing of the resource.

 *

 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response

 */

public function index($id)

{

  $msg = Notification::with('teacher.department')->where('student_id',$id)->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(10);

  $msgs = [];

  foreach($msg as $m){

    $msgs[] = [

        'id' => $m->id,

        'active' => 0,

        'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),

      ];

  }

  LaravelBatch::update('notifications',(array) $msgs,'id');

  return view('message.all',['messages'=>$msg]);

}

/**

 * Show the form for creating a new resource.

 *

 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response

 */

public function create()

{

    //

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what is your question? there is no question here

Comment: How to solve the error Mavinoo\LaravelBatch\LaravelBatch::update() should not be called statically

Answer (score 0):

So you are calling a method statically on a class that has defined that method to not be static. Usually you would get an instance of the class then call the method in this case, but most likely you are trying to use the Facade not the underlying class here.

You want to use `Mavinoo\LaravelBatch\LaravelBatchFacade` to make that call, **NOT** `Mavinoo\LaravelBatch\LaravelBatch`. Either your alias in `config/app.php` for `Batch` is not pointing to the facade **OR** where you are importing the class you are not referring to the class.

```
use Mavinoo\LaravelBatch\LaraveBatchFacade as LaravelBatch;
```

or if you have the alias setup correctly:

```
use LaravelBatch;
```

Reference the documentation for this package in the version you are using to see how the alias is to be defined.

Comment: I have this as provider: Mavinoo\LaravelBatch\LaravelBatchServiceProvider::class,

Comment: And this in aliases: 'LaravelBatch' => Mavinoo\LaravelBatch\LaravelBatchFacade::class,

Comment: what is the import statement at the top of this controller for `LaravelBatch`?

Comment: is this use Mavinoo\LaravelBatch\LaravelBatch;